# How to find documents that has field some field empty in solr 4.3.1

Tags: solr

There are bunch of answers on SO, all of them says to look at [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) page for that solution:

`-field:["" TO *]`

however, this does not work for my Solr 4.3.1 installation. I'm looking for empty fields with `string` and `text_general` types. Seem solution above looks for document that does not have that field at all. In my case field is just empty. What other way should I use to find them?

**UPDATE 1**

From what I've researched `string` fields works with `-field:["" TO *]` query, however `text_general` fields does not. How to fix it?

Comment: Solr does not index empty fields. Are you getting the blank value as a result ? -field:[* TO *] is the syntax is offical docs, i think.

Comment: No, when using  -field:[* TO *]  or  -field:["" TO *] I'm getting all documents (similar to *:*)

Comment: Do the documents returned have the field values in the response ?

Comment: i tried with both blank value and no value and -name:["" TO *] works fine for me

Comment: for `text_general` fields also?

Comment: Yup tested it  on solr 4.3 and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

For type string, I had 2 documents - 
One with

```
<str name="gender"/>
```

The other with

```
<str name="gender">male</str>
```

When I query with:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/mycore/select?q=gender%3A%22%22&wt=xml&indent=true
```

I get the document where gender is empty. Isn't that what you want?

On the other hand, to get the document where it is not empty, I used this:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/mycore/select?q=gender%3A%5B%22%22+TO+*%5D&wt=xml&indent=true
```

Comment: on that URL http://vm232.softsky.com.ua:8983/solr/#/collection1/query there are documents that has `content` and `title` fields empty. Try to query them

Comment: when I tried `q=id:"http://www.endlessllp.com/bucking-trend-women.aspx"` it gets back one record, but, when I add one more condition `q=id:"http://www.endlessllp.com/bucking-trend-women.aspx" AND content:*` response comes back with 0 documents! I see that only when content has english description this happens - because this worked `q=id:"http://g1.globo.com/economia/midia-e-marketing/noticia/2013/06/facebook-atinge-1-milhao-de-anunciantes-ativos2.html" AND content:*`